# 2D Q.H.O and degenerate time independent Perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

In the case when we consider the 2D quantum harmonic oscillator, we also consider an additional disturbance operator of the form $W=Kxy$.

If we consider the eigenvalue $E_1$, where $n=1$, these eigenvalue is twice fold degenerate.
Therefore I am dealing with time independent degenerate perturbation theory.
What I did was simply try to diagonalize the matrix of the disturbance operator in the eigenspace for $n=1$. Find the corresponding eigenvectors, which will be expressed as a linear combination of the basis kets spannig the eigenspace for n=1, and consider these new kets, as the new eigenstates of the perturbed hamiltonian $H=H_0 + Kxy$.

By doing so I found:

For the different first order correction terms of the energy eigenvalue:

$E_{1,I}^{(1)}=\frac{\hbar K}{m \omega}$.

$E_{1,II}^{(1)}=-\frac{\hbar K}{m \omega}$.

Now nomenclature:

The subscript 1 : the eigenstate

The subscirpt I,II: the first and 2nd first order correction term.

The superscript (1): the correction term order.

The corresponding eigenvectors to these eigenvalues are:

$E_{1,I}^{(1)}=\frac{\hbar K}{m \omega}\rightarrow|1\rangle_{1,I}=\frac {1}{\sqrt2} (|1,0\rangle + |0,1\rangle)$

$E_{1,II}^{(1)}=-\frac{\hbar K}{m \omega}\rightarrow|1\rangle_{1,II}=\frac {1}{\sqrt2} (|0,1\rangle - |1,0\rangle)$.

If my results are correct, and I believe they are, the problem I am facing is a personal test that I am trying to do. For example

$H_0|1\rangle=H_0|1,0\rangle=2\hbar\omega|1,0\rangle$

$H_0|1\rangle=H_0|0,1\rangle=2\hbar\omega|0,1\rangle$

Here we can see the degeneracy when the disturbance operator is not present, which means, that there is no way to lift the degeneracy.

Once the disturbance operator is present, the following is expected for the twice fold degenerate eigenstate n=1:

$E_{1,I}=E_1^{(0)}+ \lambda E_{1,I}^{(1)}$

$E_{1,II}=E_1^{(0)}+ \lambda E_{1,II}^{(1)}$

The degeneracy is lifted.

What I am trying to do is to have the disturbance Hamilonian act on the new eigenstates and have as a result the above written energy expressions. I am trying to, but my calculations give me other results.

$H|1\rangle_I=(H_0+ Kxy)(|1\rangle_0 + |1\rangle_{1,I})$

Here lies the problem:

1. For $|1\rangle_0$ (unperturbed first eigenstate) we can either have $|1,0\rangle$ or $|0,1\rangle$. While this doesn't affect the result when $H_0$ acts on it, it does affect when $Kxy$ acts on it. And this is my 2nd question:

2.The result, should be $H|1\rangle_I=E_{1,I}|1\rangle_I$ or $H|1\rangle_{II}=E_{1,II}|1\rangle_{II}$. But I don't get this.
Than I thought of only considering the eigenvectors of the eigenvalues of the disturbance operator in the subspace, as the new ones, which correspond to the perturbed hamiltonian. Even in this case, I still do not get the result I have two.

What am I doing wrong?